# How to manually compute the number of FLOPS in backward pass for a CNN like ResNet?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, deep-residual-networks

I've been trying to figure out how to compute the number of Flops in backward pass of ResNet. For forward pass, it seems straightforward: apply the conv filters to the input for each layer. But how does one do the Flops counts for  gradient computation and update of all weights during the backward pass?

Specifically,

- how to compute Flops in gradient computations for each layer?
- what all gradients need to be computed so Flops for each of those can be counted?
- How many Flops in computation of gradient for Pool, BatchNorm, and Relu layers?

I understand the chain rule for gradient computation, but having a hard time formulating how it'd apply to weight filters in conv layers of ResNet and how many Flops each of those would take. It'd be very useful to get any comments about method to compute total Flops for Backward pass. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is asking a question regarding mathematical calculations instead of a code specific solution.

Comment: cross-posted three times on stats.SO https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464578/how-to-manually-compute-number-of-ops-in-backward-pass-of-a-cnn

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely count the number of multiplication, addition for the backward pass manually, but I guess that's an exhaustive process for complex models.

Usually, most models are benchmarked with flops for a forward pass instead of backward flop count for CNN and other models. I guess the reason has to do with the **inference** being more important in terms of different CNN variants and other deep learning models in the application.

The backward pass is only important while training, and for most of the simple models, the backward and forward flops should be close with some constant factors.

So, I tried a hacky approach to calculate the gradients for the whole resnet model in the graph to get the flop counts for both forward pass and gradient calculation and then subtracted the forward flops. It's not an exact measurement, may miss many operations for a complex graph/model.

But this may give a flop estimate for most models.

**[Following code snippet works with tensorflow 2.0]**

```
import tensorflow as tf

def get_flops():

    for_flop = 0
    total_flop = 0
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()

    # forward
    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():

            model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50() # change your model here

            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()

            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
                                                  run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

            for_flop = flops.total_float_ops
            # print(for_flop)

    # forward + backward
    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():

            model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50() # change your model here


            outputTensor = model.output 
            listOfVariableTensors = model.trainable_weights
            gradients = tf.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)

            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()

            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
                                                  run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

            total_flop = flops.total_float_ops
            # print(total_flop)

    return for_flop, total_flop


for_flops, total_flops = get_flops()
print(f'forward: {for_flops}')
print(f'backward: {total_flops - for_flops}')
```

Out:

```
51112224
102224449
forward: 51112224
backward: 51112225
```

Comment: My question was more about how to do it manually, that is, look at layer, see it's filter sizes and get a count of the ops it needs it backprop, without coding. E.g. how would you do it for the 1st bottleneck block (just 3 layers) of a Resnet-50?

Comment: Don't think that's suitable for this channel.